# a div has no inherited font size from body

Tags: html, css, font-size

```css
body{
font-size:0.9em;
}

.m1{
font-size:0.9em;
}
```

```html
<div class='navt'>
<div class='m1'>LOREM</div>
<div class='m1'>LOREM</div>
</div>
```

If you remove `font-size` from `m1` you'll see that the font size changes i.e. not inherited from `body`.

I'm expecting that all divs inside `body` have a `font-size` equal to the one declared for `body`.

Don't tell me that I need to set `font-size` separately for each div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `em` it means the size is relative to its parent. You should use `rem` to make it relative to the root of the document.

In this case, the font size for `.m1` is 0.9 * 0.9 = 0.81px.

```css
body  {
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

.m1 {
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

.m2 {}

.m3 {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}

.m4 {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}
```

```html
<div class='navt'>
  <div class='m1'>LOREM</div>
  <div class='m2'>LOREM</div>
  <div class='m3'>LOREM</div>
  <div class='m4'>LOREM</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @puerto my pleasure

Answer (score 0):

body { font-size: 1em}
.text-one, .text-two, .text-three {font-size: 1em}

HaiHalloBye

Comment: Please write a few words about what your code does.

Comment: From Review:  Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks